# Structured Streaming with Flume

Tags: streaming, spark-streaming, flume

Hi can anyone tell me how to read a flume stream using spark new API for structured streaming.

**Example:**

`val lines = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()`

Answer (score 1):

As of Spark 2.1, Spark supports only File, Kafka and Socket source. Socket SOurce is meant for debugging and development and shouldn't be productionalized. This leaves File and Kafka sources.

So, the only options you have are
a) take data from FLume and dump them into S3 files. Spark can get the data from S3 files. The way the File Source works is that it watches a folder, and when a new file appears, it loads it as a microbatch
b) Funnel your events into a Kafka instance

Answer (score 0):

```
val flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createStream(streamingContext, [chosen machine's hostname], [chosen port]) for push based approach and
 val flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(streamingContext, [sink machine hostname], [sink port]) for pull-based approach
```